# using .htaccess to rename .php files .html?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

just wondering if there will be any problems renaming .php files .html files via .htaccess?
Our existing site is html and I want to update the pages with dynamic php pages, but people have links saved to the existing html site. If this isn't possible, is my only way to create html pages with iframes to wrap the php pages in?

thanks :)

Comment: It is possible, .php file can be rewrited in .html file. But the page name people have and you rewrite using `htaccess` should match

Comment: `mod_rewrite` can do it very easily, or you could just configure Apache to let PHP handle files with a .html extension and put you PHP code in .html files

Comment: if you mean you want to redirect someone from /foo/bar.html to /foo/bar.php then yes, that will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not renaming the php file to html, but just redirect the file use html extension to php files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f        # don't apply to the existing html files
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1\.php [QSA,L]  # QSA means combine query string.
```

Comment: Note that `.` in regex is "any character" so this would also match `notadocumenthtml` which would lead to `notadocumen.php` (without the `t`, as that is specified by the `.`)

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking of. I just wondered if it would effect the way the PHP files run?

Comment: @GT22 No, it will not affect how the PHP files run **UNLESS** you use one of the following `$_SERVER` keys: `SCRIPT_URI`, `SCRIPT_URL`, `REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI`, `REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL`, `REDIRECT_URL`, `REQUEST_URI` as these will now show `file.html` instead of `file.php` (even though `file.php` is the actual file executed on your server)

Answer (score 2):

i believe

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

should work for your needs (untested)